# Django CSS and JavaScript is not loading

Tags: css, django, .htaccess, passenger, cpanel

I just spent all day deploying a small Django app on cPanel. Python virtual environment set up, Django files are in, dependencies installed...

Static CSS and JavaScript files are not being loaded properly.

The cPanel host put passenger_wsgi.py inside my Django app directory with .htaccess pointing to the wsgi file, so that's what is handling the requests.

The static files are exactly where they were in development, and in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = "/path/to/public_html/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [( "static", "/path/to/myapp/static/" ),]
```

In templates/base/navigation.html (I have also tried {% load static %})

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | SG</title>
        <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/custom.js' %}"  type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
```

After running python manage.py collectstatic I get all my static files and the only page that actually loads my static files is the landing page.

Any other page (admin, blog, etc.) seems to shove the app/dir name into the link/script tag causing errors.

[image: added /blog/ between domain and static url]

[image: added /admin/ between domain and static url]

And in my templates/blog/blogs.html

```
{% extends 'base/navigation.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    {% for blog in blogs %}
        ...
```

Has anyone encountered this before? What is causing the request to do this?

I've been staring at this all day so if there's any details missing please let me know, I'm taking a break.

Comment: Django doesnt serve static files in production. You have to setup them separately. It depends on your server.

Comment: Your urls might be relative, that would explain them only working on the landing page. Try changing `js/jquery.min.js` to `/js/jquery.min.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In your html template try this:

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
```